# Powershell: install RDS Terminal Server Gateway SSL Certificate

Tags: windows, powershell, ssl-certificate, remote-desktop-gateway

I have a very simple Powershell script to renew SSL certificates. We are using short duration SSL and this is a repetitive process. On our TSG (Terminal Server Gateway), I automated the IIS certificate portion without a glitch, however I'm having issues doing the same on the gateway.

I attempted two options:

```
# $NewThumb obtained elsewhere from the certificate 
$settings = Get-WmiObject                                   `
            -class          "Win32_TSGatewayServerSettings" `
            -namespace      "root\cimv2\TerminalServices"   `
            -ComputerName   "localhost"                     `
            -Authentication 6 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if ($settings){
    $h="Not Available"
    $settings | fl  # test ONE
    if ($settings.CertHash){
        # convert binary to hex ascii
        $h=""; $settings.CertHash | % {$H+=$_.Tostring("X2") }
    }
    write-host "TH: $NewThumb CH: $h"
    if ($NewThumb -eq $h){
        write-host "We have the correct certificate"
    }else {
    # convert back to byte array 
    $certthumbprint= for ( $i=0; $i -lt $NewThumb.length; $i+=2) { [System.Convert]::ToByte($NewThumb.Substring( $i,2),16) } 
    $settings.SetCertificate($certthumbprint) | Out-Null
    # test if change is effective
    $settings = Get-WmiObject                           `
        -class          "Win32_TSGatewayServerSettings" `
        -namespace      "root\cimv2\TerminalServices"   `
        -ComputerName   "localhost"                     `
        -Authentication 6 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $settings | fl
    write-host "$($MySelf) New SSL Certificate Installed."
}
```

Result, BEFORE

> ```
> __GENUS                         : 2
> __CLASS                         : Win32_TSGatewayServerSettings
> __SUPERCLASS                    : 
> __DYNASTY                       : Win32_TSGatewayServerSettings
> __RELPATH                       : Win32_TSGatewayServerSettings.MaxConnections=4294967295
> __PROPERTY_COUNT                : 23
> __DERIVATION                    : {}
> __SERVER                        : TSG
> __NAMESPACE                     : root\cimv2\TerminalServices
> __PATH                          :\\TSG\root\cimv2\TerminalServ......
> adminMessageEndTime             :
> adminMessageStartTime           : 
> adminMessageText                :
> AuthenticationPluginCLSID       : 
> AuthenticationPluginDescription :
> AuthenticationPluginName        : native
> AuthorizationPluginCLSID        :  
> AuthorizationPluginDescription  :
> AuthorizationPluginName         : native  
> CentralCAPEnabled               : False
> CertHash                        : 
> consentMessageText              :  
> EnforceChannelBinding           : True
> IsConfigured                    : True
> MaxConnections                  : 4294967295 
> MaximumAllowedConnectionsBySku  : 4294967295
> MaxLogEvents                    : 7
> MaxProtocols                    : 2
> OnlyConsentCapableClients       : False
> RequestSOH                      : False
> SkuName                         : Windows Server Datacenter
> SslBridging                     : 0 
> UnlimitedConnections            : True
> PSComputerName                  : TSG
> ```

Result, AFTER

> ```
> ..... removed
> CertHash                        : {185, 13, 12, 196...}
> ..... removed
> ```

now,the second option (elegant, less code):

```
# $NewThumb obtained elsewhere from the certificate 
Import-Module RemoteDesktopServices -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
write-host "Before"
$th=Get-Item -Path RDS:\GatewayServer\SSLCertificate\Thumbprint
$th | fl  
Set-Item RDS:\GatewayServer\SSLCertificate\Thumbprint -Value $NewThumb 
write-host "after"    
$TH=Get-Item -Path RDS:\GatewayServer\SSLCertificate\Thumbprint
$th | fl
```

Before

> certhash
> NULL

After

> certhash
> {185, 13, 12, 196...}

My issue is that when run, either methods, the Thumbprint is correctly set and display on both 'After', but, if I run the script again, on both cases the Thumbprint is initially NULL. Looks like a missing 'commit' on SQL.

I'm running this remotely on invoke-command on the tsg server.

Answer (score 3):

You need to ensure the TSGateway service is stopped before you set the thumbprint. So in your second example you should do:

```
# $NewThumb obtained elsewhere from the certificate 
Import-Module RemoteDesktopServices -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Stop-Service TSGateway
write-host "Before"
$th=Get-Item -Path RDS:\GatewayServer\SSLCertificate\Thumbprint
$th | fl  
Set-Item RDS:\GatewayServer\SSLCertificate\Thumbprint -Value $NewThumb
Start-Service TSGateway 
write-host "after"    
$TH=Get-Item -Path RDS:\GatewayServer\SSLCertificate\Thumbprint
$th | fl
```

This is sadly not documented but this has been my experience after setting this up internally at Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RemoteDesktop module commands to install this cert for you

Either load from PFX file on disk

```
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "yourPFXpassword" -AsPlainText -Force
Set-RDCertificate -Role RDGateway -ImportPath "C:\Certificates\NewCert.pfx" -Password $Password
```

Or load from cert already in your cert store

```
Set-RDCertificate -Role RDGateway -Thumbprint aedd995b45e633d4ef30fcbc8f3a48b627e9a28c
```

From https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/remotedesktop/set-rdcertificate?view=winserver2012r2-ps

Comment: Thanks, however, it gives me:
**Set-RDCertificate : deployment does not contain an RD Gateway.** Our TSG is just that, nothing else installed/configured.

Comment: Could you clarify what your “TSG” is if you don’t have a RD Gateway?

Comment: My bad... TSG is the old 'Terminal Server Gateway', today is referred as __RD Gateway__, managed by the **RD Gateway Manager**.